# Is it possible to saveas pdf in MsWord including Headings and Word bookmarks options? I need both

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, bookmarks

I want Headings Bookmarks and Word Bookmarks when saving the word document as PDF. Is it possible? I need both option output as shown in the following screen.

[image]

Comment: The picture your shared is the settings in Word 2007. In Word 2013 and later version, there is no setting to do it.

Comment: @WinniL, beg to differ. I'm on 2013 Pro and that dialog is still there on the SaveAs dialog. Click the Options button.

Ahmed, as far as I can tell from my quick test, the Word Bookmarks choice is disabled. I couldn't even choose it.